# Embedding .NET usercontrol in IE8

Tags: .net, internet-explorer-8

I have a simple webpage containing a .NET usercontrol embedded using the OBJECT tag. In IE7, the page displays and I can use the usercontrol.

However, in IE8, the usercontrol does not even load.

Any thoughts / ideas?

Answer (score 2):

This is a change in IE8 due to a vulnerability in assembly loading. See [this post](http://blogs.msdn.com/askie/archive/2009/05/22/net-control-no-longer-loads-in-ie8-in-internet-zone.aspx) for more details.

The control will load if the site is added to the Trusted Sites list. There is no way to do that from the web, so the users have to do it themselves or you can provide some kind of installer which does it. (See msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537181(VS.85).aspx )

Compatibility mode or the X-UA-Compatible meta tag has no effect.

Comment: Correct, and we'd strongly advise moving away from UserControls as they are now deprecated.

Comment: @EricLaw -MSFT - Easier said than done for some apps.  For example, SilverLight can't display TIFFs.

Comment: I never said it would be easy, only a good idea. Stating the obvious-- TIFF is generally not a good choice of file format, given the lack of compression and huge file sizes.

Comment: TIFF is pretty much the standard for industries that depend on scanned images.  Plus, TIFF doesn't lack compression - it supports many types of compression.  For bitonal images, TIFFs typically provide the best lossless compression.  Hopefully with the push for making healthcare paperless, Microsoft will make Silverlight a viable platform for delivering scanned documents in TIFF format.

Answer (score 1):

The user control will load if you'll add the site in to the Trusted Sites list.
This is by design (Confirmed with Microsoft support team).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the solution to the problem but at least until someone can offer a better answer you can put:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7" />
```

right below the title tag in the head of your page.  This will force the page to render in IE7 and should show the usercontrol again.